# Any way to receive message, being a process on SYSTEM user

Tags: windows, winapi, ipc, win32-process

So, is there any particular way to do this in Windows?

There's a service, that autostarts under SYSTEM user at every boot. By default, as stated at [To schedule a task that runs with system permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/schtasks-create#to-schedule-a-task-that-runs-with-system-permissions), any process, started on SYSTEM account, can't receive any information from other processes, i.e. using `PostThreadMessage` or `SendMessage`. `ChangeWindowMessageFilter` doesn't help.

So now, I have to do something like:

1. Save data to local users directory (that's done by client app).
2. Server every `n` seconds searches for a client process. If exists, server gets `username`, that started client process and in `username`'s folder collects data.

The thing is: client needs to send little portion of data (< 50 Mb) to the storage. That could be done only with elevated permissions. So there's an elevated server that accepts this little portions of data.

Comment: "*any process started on SYSTEM account can't receive any information from other processes*" - that is not true. "*ChangeWindowMessageFilter doesn't help*" - likely because a service runs in a different session/desktop than user processes, and window messages can't cross session/desktop boundaries. "*client needs to send little portion of data*" - you can have the client communicate with the service using a named pipe, TCP socket, ActiveX/COM, RPC, etc. There are many forms of IPC that are not dependent on the file system.

Comment: @RemyLebeau , I'll try those methods you've stated, thank you.

Comment: in what problem use pipes, shared memory, etc ? of course save data to disk and poll - absolute wrong solution